# ASP.NET 2.2 Signalr Core Getting the connection Ids of all participants within a specific room

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, asp.net-core, signalr

I'd like to know how to get all the connectionIds of all participants within a specific chat room. Currently, I am able to store the details of participants in a chat room. However, since I am unable to manually set the connectionIds, how can I ensure that the next time they rejoin a room, that the messages are delivered to them?

Also, what is the purpose of a group? And how do I use it?

ChatHub.cs

```
[Authorize]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = new ConnectionMapping<string>();
        private ChatSessionData chatSessionData;
        private ChatParticipantData chatParticipantData;
        private ChatMessageData chatMessageData;
        private ChatConnectionData chatConnectionData;

        public ChatHub(ChatSessionData chatSessionData, ChatConnectionData chatConnectionData, ChatParticipantData chatParticipantData, ChatMessageData chatMessageData)
        {
            this.chatSessionData = chatSessionData;
            this.chatParticipantData = chatParticipantData;
            this.chatMessageData = chatMessageData;
            this.chatConnectionData = chatConnectionData;
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
            var SessionId = httpContext.Request.Query["SessionId"];
            var UserId = Context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "ChatSampleId").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
            var users = chatConnectionData.GetBySessionId(SessionId);
            List<string> connectionIds = new List<string>();
            if (users.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in users)
                {
                    connectionIds.Add(item.ConnectionId);
                }
                CreateChatMessageViewModel ccmvm = new CreateChatMessageViewModel
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    UserId = UserId,
                    SessionId = SessionId,
                    Name = user,
                    Message = message,
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
                };
                chatMessageData.Save(ccmvm);
                //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage",user, message);
                await Clients.Clients(connectionIds).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
            }

        }

        public async Task SessionNotification(string user, string message)
        {
            var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
            var SessionId = httpContext.Request.Query["SessionId"];
            var UserId = Context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "ChatSampleId").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
            var users = chatConnectionData.GetBySessionId(SessionId);
            List<string> connectionIds = new List<string>();
            if (users.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in users)
                {
                    connectionIds.Add(item.ConnectionId);
                }
                connectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
            }
            else
            {
                connectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
            }
            //if only have one connectionid, send the message anyway
            await Clients.Clients(connectionIds).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
            var SessionId = httpContext.Request.Query["SessionId"];
            var UserName = Context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserName").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
            var UserId = Context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "ChatSampleId").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
            var chatSession = chatParticipantData.GetBySessionIdAndUserId(SessionId, UserId);
            if (chatSession == null)
            {
                //New Connection
                CreateChatParticipantViewModel ccpvm = new CreateChatParticipantViewModel
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    SessionId = SessionId,
                    UserId = UserId
                };
                chatParticipantData.Save(ccpvm);
                CreateChatMessageViewModel ccmvm = new CreateChatMessageViewModel
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    UserId = UserId,
                    SessionId = SessionId,
                    Name = UserName,
                    Message = "has joined the conversation",
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
                };
                chatMessageData.Save(ccmvm);
                SessionNotification(UserName, "has joined the conversation");
                CreateChatConnectionViewModel cccvm = new CreateChatConnectionViewModel
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
                    UserAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"],
                    Connected = true,
                    SessionId = SessionId,
                    UserId = UserId,
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
                };
                chatConnectionData.Save(cccvm);
                Groups.AddToGroupAsync(cccvm.ConnectionId, UserName);

            }
            else
            {
                var connectionDetails = chatConnectionData.GetBySessionIdAndUserId(SessionId, UserId);
                if (connectionDetails != null)
                {
                    //save the connectionId or Group details to the database and reload it
                    Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionDetails.ConnectionId, UserName);
                }
            }
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you are looking up the data are you positive neither SessionId nor UserId have changed on re-connect? SessionId kind of screams it could be different.

Comment: Session Id is just the chat rooms Id and its the same. I just realized that I need to know how to get the list of users and their current connectionids in that room/group. I can't store connectionId because its different each time and it cannot be assigned manually.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is that how can I get the list of connection Id's within a room? What is the purpose of a group? I don't understand it.

Comment: Please update your question description. It is not clear what way it is behaving now and what you are actually expecting now.

Comment: Done it. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short answer to your question is... "what is the purpose of a group? And how do I use it?"

> Groups in SignalR provide a method for broadcasting messages to specified subsets of connected clients. A group can have any number of clients, and a client can be a member of any number of groups

For details about the group please visit this official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)

Note: In your case a group can be used to represent a chat room.

Answer to your second question... "how can I ensure that the next time they rejoin a room, that the messages are delivered to them?"

I believe you need maintain/persist the chat history of a room in persistent storage like in database or maybe within your ChatHub(it depends on your business domain). So that every time a new user joins or rejoins a room he/she can see all previous messages within that room. It would be the responsibility of ChatHub to send chat history to each new joining user.

Answer to question: " But how do I ensure that the person joining the room will get the new messages?"

Whenever a person connects to the chatHub you need to store his connectionId against the room like:

```
Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Your Chat Room Name");
```

Once the new user is added to the group, the next time you broadcast the message in a group the newly joined user will also get the message. Like so:

```
Clients.Group("Your chat room name").SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. The thing is, I already persist the history in the chat room. But how do I ensure that the person joining the room will get the new messages? Is it via groups? Currently I tried to store the connectionId but that doesn't work as I cannot manually assign it to the user

Comment: @JianYA, I've updated the answer. I would also recommend that you go through the SignalR official documentation as well to fully understand how Groups and ConnectionIds are maintained by SignalR hub and how they actually work.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: what do you mean? Do I change the index to Context.ConnectionId?